# How to increase CPU usage on a slow network dependent program? VB.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, performance

I have a network heavy program. After running diagnostics/profiler in my visual studio I see that the bottle neck is the repeated use of Net.HttpWebResponse.GetResponse(), specifically it goes and pings the devices with a HTTP string for information. And repeats for however many devices that respond to a broadcast packet sent out via pcapdotnet.

There are three different classes that talk to IP devices on my network for information. I.e. "what's your configuration/date/time/resolution, ip camera". I've sped it up a bit by narrowing down the http requests to one or two lines per class, so I only send it off the network as few times as possible.

So the program is slow *wall clock* time but it uses very little CPU. What are some ideas on how I can move the speed to higher CPU clocks to increase the speed to compensate for the network dependency?

**What I have tried:** So I tried multithreading the call of the three classes (i.e. Devicebrand1, devicebrand2,devicebrand3) .start() at one time and waiting until they're all 3 threads are done. This doesn't really save me any time though. Would backgroundworker be speedier?

**EDIT:** Some were confused by my wording. The "tl:dr" version is how can I make my GetResponse() faster or my using my other code many times faster to make up for the GetResponse's speed issues. Another possibility is how can I implement these function calls faster (which some mention basically only multithreading is the option).

Comment: I'm not sure how increasing CPU usage would make network requests go faster... or am I misreading the question?

Comment: faster cpu won't help if the network's the bottleneck. what's the point of having a formula 1 racecar in your garage if your house is connected to the outside world by a bumpy dirt path? You'd just be burning cpu cycles waiting for things completely outside of your program's control. Speed up the network - e.g. re-use already open connections, cache DNS information, etc...

Comment: Didn't mean to be confusing! I'm okay with increasing CPU I just didn't think it would make the network faster. I meant it would make everything else faster around it to make up for it. I'm also looking for faster getresponse() alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Your question title is rather confusing. You're trying to speed up the program and get round the network latency problem, not artificially increase CPU usage (which won't help you at all).

If you really need all the network access, there's not much you can do beyond multithreading. The multithreading won't make a huge saving, because you've still got the same overall traffic flowing, but it will make a bit of difference, because you might be uploading and downloading at the same time, and the waits for a response can all happen at the same together.